# add the image for each listview item in out of the listview

Tags: android

Hi i want to add the particular image for each listView item left side .but that is not included in the listview ,see the image from below link
[Image](http://i51.tinypic.com/6ntwdh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one scrollview in taht scrollview take 2 linearlayouts as horizontal and then assign images to one linear layout as vertical and add listview to another layout

Comment: Can you scroll listview in scrollview? I guess you cannot :)

Comment: i want total page scrolling .By using above i got

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are talking about the image with red circle. This is functionality of Iphone and not available in android by default. You will have to create custom listview and make the image part of the list item. It cannot be outside listview. That way it will be difficult to access it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters. It works.